# How do I add jQuery plugins on my rails app

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I will use the GMAP3 Plugin for JQuery in my rails app.

I already put the javascript file in `app/assets/javascripts/gmap3/gmap3.min.js`.

I will use this jQuery plugin only on the welcome page.
What files do I need to modify (and how) in order to make use the plugin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should put the file ( for a Rails 3 project ) in `vendor/assets/javascripts/gmap3.min.js` and then you should add it in two ways:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'gmap3.min' %>
```

or in some added file like

```
//In (for example) application.js

//= require gmap3.min
```

If you added the file correctly, that is, in a page that you are seeing (you can check this in your browser console, usually in `Resources` or `Network` ), you can use it.

Some links for you to see:

- http://railsapps.github.io/rails-javascript-include-external.html
- http://railscasts.com/episodes/279-understanding-the-asset-pipeline?view=asciicast

Comment: Just one question, why in vendor, why not in assets?

Comment: From the second link I provided you can get some info, but basically: > "If our app uses a jQuery plugin then the /vendor/assets directory is a good place for its JavaScript files as these are something that’s maintained by someone else."

Comment: vendor/assets/ because GMAP3 is a third party software. if YOU developed the library, then you should put it in assets/

Comment: Inside vendor, can I open another folder like gmap3 and place the javascript in it?

Comment: Yes, but be careful with the route, it wont be `gmap3.min` but `gmap3/gmap3.min`

Comment: hmm thanks a lot. One last question, if I want to use it on one of the pages instead of on application.js, will I need to create welcome.js in `app/assets/javascripts/` ?

Comment: Not necessary, you can use the first option that I wrote and place it in your desired view ( `<%= javascript_include_tag 'gmap3.min' %>` remember the folder here, but it works on vendor). Try it!

Comment: Nico, would it be possible to chat on Skype or somewhere, I live in New York so its 2:49PM here right now.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm heading of to university now and I have work and an exam tommorrow.